# php habilitar fila de tabla

Tags: php, javascript

Buenas tardes.
el caso es que tengo una tabla que se llena desde una base de datos y necesito colocarle un checkbox que cuando lo seleccione me habilite solo esa fila, el codigo php de la tabla es:

```
<?php
    $sql = "Select * FROM usuarios, estado, roles Where estado.id_estado = usuarios.id_estado AND roles.id_rol = usuarios.id_rol";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    echo "
        <br>
        <br>
        <table id='usuarios' border = 1 cellspacing = 1 cellpadding = 1>
            <tr>
                <th>Identificacion</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>Direccion</th>
                <th>Fecha de registro</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Rol</th>
            </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "
            <tr class='item'>
                <td>
                    <input name='ident' class='cajas' type='text' id='ident' value=" . $row['identificacion'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td>
                    <input name='nombre' class='cajas' type='text' id='nombre' value=" . $row['nombre'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td>
                    <input name='apellido' class='cajas' type='text' id='apellido' value=" . $row['apellido'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td>
                    <input name='telefono' class='cajas' type='text' id='telefono' value=" . $row['telefono'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td>
                    <input name='direccion' class='cajas' type='text' id='direccion' value=" . $row['direccion'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td>
                    <input name='fecha' class='cajas' type='text' id='fecha' value=" . $row['fecha_registro'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td>
                    <input name='estado' class='cajas' type='text' id='estado' value=" . $row['estado'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td> 
                    <input name='rol' class='cajas' type='text' id='rol' value=" . $row['tipo'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td>
                    <input type='checkbox'>
                </td>" .
            "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

No sé si sea posible con una función JS, he intentado con la propiedad `OnClick` en el check pero no me funciona

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad de StackOverflow :)

Comment: La pregunta no está muy clara, amigo. Te recomiendo ser más específico, para poder ayudarte como esperas.

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agrega el `JS` que has intentado y no te funciono.

Comment: ese codigo me trae los datos de la tabla y digamos que son 10 registros, añadi una columna donde tengo un checkbox, y lo que necesito es que si selecciono un checkbox le quite la propiedad disabled a esa fila, pero no lo he logrado hacer, no se si me estoy enrredando mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas, se puede hacer con el evento onchange, se puede hacer de varias forma, tal vez está no sea la forma más correcta pero he intentado que afecte lo menos posible tú código.

Básicamente esta función lo que hace es buscar si existe el disabled en el en la sintaxis del padre tr, y dependiendo de si lo encuentra o no, lo introduce o lo machaca.

```js
function changeDisable(e) {
  const parent =  e.parentNode.parentNode;
  const text = parent.innerHTML;
  if (text.indexOf("disabled") !== -1) {
    parent.innerHTML = text.replace(new RegExp('disabled', 'g'), "");
    return;
  }
  parent.innerHTML  = text.replace(new RegExp('type="text"', 'g'), 'type="text" disabled');
}
```

```html
<?php
    $sql = "Select * FROM usuarios, estado, roles Where estado.id_estado = usuarios.id_estado AND roles.id_rol = usuarios.id_rol";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    echo "
        <br>
        <br>
        <table id='usuarios' border = 1 cellspacing = 1 cellpadding = 1>
            <tr>
                <th>Habilitar</th>
                <th>Identificacion</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>Direccion</th>
                <th>Fecha de registro</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Rol</th>
            </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "
            <tr class='item'>
                <td>  <input type='checkbox' onchange='changeDisable(this)'> </td>
                <td>
                    <input name='ident' class='cajas' type='text' id='ident' value=" . $row['identificacion'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td>
                    <input name='nombre' class='cajas' type='text' id='nombre' value=" . $row['nombre'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td>
                    <input name='apellido' class='cajas' type='text' id='apellido' value=" . $row['apellido'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td>
                    <input name='telefono' class='cajas' type='text' id='telefono' value=" . $row['telefono'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td>
                    <input name='direccion' class='cajas' type='text' id='direccion' value=" . $row['direccion'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td>
                    <input name='fecha' class='cajas' type='text' id='fecha' value=" . $row['fecha_registro'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td>
                    <input name='estado' class='cajas' type='text' id='estado' value=" . $row['estado'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td> 
                    <input name='rol' class='cajas' type='text' id='rol' value=" . $row['tipo'] . " disabled>
                </td>" .
                "<td>
                    <input type='checkbox'>
                </td>" .
            "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score -5):

Pues yo hice algo parecido mira si te sirve y acomoda lo a lo tuyo.

Hazlo con un onchange llamando al js.

le das un name y le pones onchange

```
name="ejemplo" onchange="cambia_visibles(this)"
```

```
function cambia(elemento) {
    if (elemento.value === "checked") {
        document.getElementById("ejemplo").disabled = "true";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ejemplo").disabled = "false";
    }
}
```